# Simple Physics 1 question regarding position of a particle at a time $t$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, vectors

I am going over my physics homework before an exam, and noticed I genuinely had no clue how to do the following:

Given the vector V, plot the path on an xy plane, where t is in seconds.

### $$V = (5m)\sin(2\pi t)i + (5m)\cos(2\pi t)j$$

So I tried thinking about it critically and then I ran into something that made me question this whole problem.

Let x and t be some different constants,

$x(\sin(2\pi t)) = 0$, regardless of what x or t you give it.

$x(\cos(2\pi t)) = x$, regardless of what x or t you give it.

From this I substitute the previous findings into the original equation

### $$V = 0i + xj$$

This doesn't really make sense to me, and I am not sure how to go about plotting this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Evaluating $\vec V \cdot \vec V$ could help you as might looking up “Lissajous figures”?

Comment: Try finding the Cartesian equation rather than the parametric equation. What happens if you add the square of x to the square of y?

Comment: Is $V$ supposed to be the velocity of the moving object? And you are supposed to plot its position? That will take a small amount of calculus.

Comment: $V$ is the position of the particle

Comment: OK. That’s a confusing notation for position!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your “regardless” statements about sin and cos are both wrong.

For example, when $t=1/4$, $\sin{2\pi t}=\sin{\pi/2}=1$.

Get a calculator and plot the points $(5\sin{2\pi t},5\cos{2\pi t})$ for $t=0.0,0.1,0.2,0.3,...,1.0$.

Comment: Ah I see! I was thinking while t is an integer. That might be best for me to just split 0->1 up to potentially graph this, but after t = 1, I believe that this will just be flat?

Comment: Use your calculator to keep going from 1.0 to 2.0. It won’t be flat.

Comment: I am guessing that when you learned trig you were taught that sin and cos are related to ratios of sides of right triangles. They are, but you should have been taught that they give the coordinates of points on a unit circle.

Comment: Oh now I see my mistake...